# Animate during a range of values

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, css-transitions

I created a cursor that animates its color when you move it. It goes from a shade of blue to a red. When you are not moving the cursor, the animation is paused.

The cursor's amount of pixels traveled is being counted (`var mousetravel`) and is displayed in the upper left corner of the screen. This variable is updated every 20 milliseconds.

Right now, the cursor's animation is done with CSS. However, that relies on there being an animation duration. Right now that duration is set to 4 seconds.

So, basically, if you continually move the cursor, the change in color would be complete after 4 seconds. What I want to do is have the change in color complete once the cursor has moved 10000 pixels; I want the color change to be dependent on the cursor's amount of pixels traveled, not on a timed duration like it currently is.

I'm really not sure how I should approach this.

I hope this makes sense. I'll be happy to clarify anything.

[Here is the jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8bpucqzv/1/)

The jsfiddle has more code, but I'll post the code that specifically deals with what I'm talking about here:

**HTML**

```
<div class='cursor_transistion' id='cursor'>
    &nbsp;
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.cursor_transistion {
    animation-name: cursor_transistion;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    animation-play-state: running;
}

@keyframes cursor_transistion {
    0% {background-color: #7AA8CE;}
    100% {background-color: #CE7A7A;}
}
```

**JS**

```
var $mouseX = 0, $mouseY = 0;
var $xp = 0, $yp =0;

$(document).mousemove(function(e){
    $mouseX = e.pageX;
    $mouseY = e.pageY;    
});

var $loop = setInterval(function(){
// change 12 to alter damping higher is slower
$xp += (($mouseX - $xp)/12);
$yp += (($mouseY - $yp)/12);
$("#cursor").css({left:$xp +'px', top:$yp +'px'});  
}, 30);

var timestamp = null;
var lastMouseX = null;
var lastMouseY = null;

var mrefreshinterval = 500; // update display every 500ms
 var lastmousex=-1; 
 var lastmousey=-1;
 var lastmousetime;
 var mousetravel = 0;
 var lastmousetravel = 0;

//pauses CSS color animation while cursor is not moving
setInterval(function () {
        if (lastmousetravel === mousetravel){
            $('.cursor_transistion').css('animation-play-state', 'paused');
        } else {
            $('.cursor_transistion').css('animation-play-state', 'running');
        }
    }, 20);

 $('html').mousemove(function(e) {
     var mousex = e.pageX;
     var mousey = e.pageY;
     if (lastmousex > -1)
         mousetravel += Math.max( Math.abs(mousex-lastmousex), Math.abs(mousey-lastmousey) );
     lastmousex = mousex;
     lastmousey = mousey;
     var speed = lastmousex + lastmousey;

    setTimeout(function(){
        lastmousetravel = mousetravel;
    }, 20);
});
```

Comment: Very cool fiddle btw.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an idea, not tested, but maybe instead of using a CSS transition to change the color, use RGB coloring and just set the color as the mouse moves. Basically, at each interval up to 10000px set it to a new color at each update based on the number of pixels moved. That also would get rid of the need to pause and stop the transition if the color is dependent on the number of pixels moved. With this solution, however, you would need to devise a formula to determine the color.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea. I think I've got a formula that might work. I'll try it out in a little bit. Thanks!

Comment: Let us know if you come up with a solution